# Buildroot Negation Mark

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, buildroot

I Don't  understand  the purpose of redefining the **BR2_USE_WCHAR**  with Negation  after the comment.

```
config BR2_PACKAGE_RRDTOOL
        bool "rrdtool"
        depends on **BR2_USE_WCHAR**
        select BR2_PACKAGE_FREETYPE
        select BR2_PACKAGE_LIBART
        select BR2_PACKAGE_LIBPNG
        select BR2_PACKAGE_ZLIB
        help
          RRDtool is the OpenSource industry standard, high performance
          data logging and graphing system for time series data.

          http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/

comment "rrdtool needs a toolchain w/ wchar"
        depends on **!BR2_USE_WCHAR**
```

Comment: The use of comments with dependencies is explained in the Buildroot user manual [Dependencies on target and toolchain options](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#dependencies-target-toolchain-options): "**Additionally, for dependencies on toolchain options, a `comment` should be displayed when the option is not enabled, so that the user knows why the package is not available.**"

Answer (score 1):

The `BR2_PACKAGE_RRDTOOL` entry depends on `BR2_USE_WCHAR`, so will only be visible if `BR2_USE_WCHAR` is defined.

The comment depends on `!BR2_USE_WCHAR`, and so will be shown if `BR2_USE_WCHAR` is **not** defined.

In other words:

- `BR2_USE_WCHAR` defined: `BR2_PACKAGE_RRDTOOL` entry visible, and comment hidden
- `BR2_USE_WCHAR` not defined: `BR2_PACKAGE_RRDTOOL` entry hidden, and comment visible